# Cheap solution to connect PC to TV

Tags: pc, hdmi, television, vga

My desktop PC does not have a HDMI port, but my TV only supports HDMI inputs. Is there any way of connecting the two that is

- Cheap
- Reasonably reliable and
- Ensures a reasonable image quality

I have 2gb DDR2 RAM.Budget around 10 dollar or 700 to 900 indian rupees.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. I've modified your question a little to give more precise requirements. If possible, please give us your budget, any additional requirements and the country you require shipping to.

Comment: Desktop or laptop PC?

Comment: @user3169 desktop.

Comment: What outputs does your computer have?

Comment: As your PC doesn't has a HDMI output, I'm assuming it has a VGA one. For such situations there are small converters to connect them anyways. I'd just go to the nearest tech market and ask for one - I don't recommend to buy it on the internet; I once did and got a converter that didn't worked for a relatively high price. Depending on the converter you get you maybe need a VGA/HDMI cable also (if you haven't already got one). Using the converter always means a lose of quality, but that shouldn't be a problem if you don't want to display something in ultra HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do....

### Option 1:  VGA to HDMI Adapter

The cheapest one I found with relatively good ratings was (at the time of this post) $17 available on [Amazon](http://amzn.to/1UbNJ9M).  VGA being an analog signal and HDMI being digital, there's no getting around the fact that you have to convert the signal.

*Note:  You will need to supply your own HDMI cable to go from the adapter to your TV*

[image: VGA to HDMI]

### Option 2:  Upgrade Video Card to DVI and use a DVI to HDMI Cable

You said you had a desktop computer, so you could easily add (or replace) your existing video card with one that had a DVI connector.  These are selling for as low as $5.95 (at the time of this post) on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo&_udhi=10&_nkw=dvi%20video%20card&rt=nc&LH_FS=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684).  Keep in mind that this is going to be a used video adapter, but given the price constraints, I don't think this will be too much of an issue.

You can then use a DVI to HDMI cable to connect that video card to your TV.  [Amazon](http://amzn.to/1UbPhAy) has it for $6.95 (at the time of this post). Since DVI and HDMI are both digital, no digital to analog conversion is necessary

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, there are no options that I could readily find for under the $10 limit.  The second option I proposed seems to be the cheapest, coming in at about $13 USD.

Answer (score 3):

This [VGA to HDMI with audio adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006FILNV6) is what you are looking for. It costs a little more than you were hoping, but there aren't many of these things around, and it has a lot of good reviews.

- $22.42
- Converts VGA Source to HDMI Display
- Supports Audio Function for HDMI Monitor and TV
- Powered by USB Port
- Cable Length: 8"
  [image: VGA to HDMI adapterlll]

Comment: then a GPU would be better for that cost

Comment: anything cheaper?

Comment: If you can find a GPU for less than $22.42 that supports HDMI, then you should give me the link so I can post it to Ripley's believe it or not.

Comment: here is the link.but it cost 25 dollar.[link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?N=100007709%204093&IsNodeId=1&Submit=ene)

Comment: At that price, you'd be better off getting the graphics card instead of the adapter.